# C language determine length of array depending on amount of digits entered by the user

Tags: c

I have the below code in which a user enters their card number, with this each digit is stored as an element in the variable array `digits[]`.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the `for` loop stop after it has stored all digits, however, I am struggling to set the loop as per the length of the entered card number.

I have tried the below code using `sizeof(cardNo)` stored in the variable length and setting length as the loop condition.

Let's say the user enters 1234 the result I am receiving with the below code being run is 43210000, when what I am looking for is just 4321.

if I set `int digits` to `digits[4]` and the loop condition to < 4 it will give me 4321 but obviously this restricts me to user only entering 4 digits when in fact I want this to be flexible i.e. if they enter 6 digits it will give me 123456 if they enter 8 digits it will give me 12345678 etc.

Any ideas or suggestions, please?

```
long cardNo = get_long("Enter Card Number: ");
int length = sizeof(cardNo);
int count = 0;
int digits[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  digits[i] = cardNo % 10;
  cardNo /= 10;
  printf("%i\n", digits[i]);
} 
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Allocate the maximum. And again, as in every question for this exercise (and there are hundresds around) I suggest to use string representation of the number rather than numerical value, unless there are strict requirements.

Comment: First: Use malloc to this allocate dynamically memoery. Second: `length` should be `size_t` type. I think `cardNo` too unless you want negative number handle.

Comment: `sizeof(cardNo)` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @IgorGalczak It doesn't have to be `size_t`.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I write **should be** because of: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT01-C.+Use+rsize_t+or+size_t+for+all+integer+values+representing+the+size+of+an+object

Comment: Actual credit/debit/payment card numbers are always at least 13 (decimal) digits and usually 16, and in some (currently rare) cases up to 19. C `long` is not required to be more than and usually is exactly 32 bits including sign, which can represent all 9-decimal-digit numbers and some 10-digit but nothing larger. Even on rare systems where `long` is 64 bits, it can represent some but not all 19-digit numbers. Don't treat card 'numbers' as numbers, treat them as strings that happen to contain digits. And of course if these were real cards you must encrypt or hash them, google PCI DSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a number is based on its logarithm base 10:

```
#include <math.h> //log10
....
    int len = log10(cardNo) + 1;
...
```

Don't forget to link with the math library (`gcc ... -lm`)

Comment: @Joshua: the argument `cardNo` is automatically converted to `double`

Comment: @pmg this seems to do the trick, thanks.  Could you be kind enough to give me a quick explanation behind the code?  This way I will know what's going on for next time :)

Comment: This is what logarithms do. `log10(x)` is the number you have to raise 10 to to obtain `x`. `10^3` (power, not xor) is `1000`, so `log10(1000)` is 3; I add `1` to get 4. `log10(4863)` is `3.<something>` and it needs 4 digits. The assigment to an integer discards anything after the decimal point.

Comment: @Coder: Fails for 999999999999999, 9999999999999999, 99999999999999999, 999999999999999999

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Joshua. To OP: you may want to limit input within `getLong()`.

Answer (score 0):

Idiom: measure-allocate-generate.

```
size_t n =0;
for (; i < cardno; ) {
  cardNo /= 10;
  n++;
} 
if(!n)n++;//0
int*digits=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is not a good idea, modifications may yield errors.

Comment: @Jose: Calls to malloc without `*sizeof()` are really bad ideas unless `char`.

Comment: I think @Jose meant that `int *digits = malloc(n * sizeof *digits);` will make it easier to avoid errors in case digits change type (`struct baseddigit *digits = malloc(n * sizeof (int)) /* error here */;`). @Jose: excuse me for butting in :)

Comment: Yes, exactly @pmg. Thank you for your explanation, definitely better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The code may be simpler, considering a maximum amount of numbers (being developer's choice to store the fixed-size container on the stack, as static, etc):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x

#define MAX_NUMBERS 16

int main() {
    char cardNum[MAX_NUMBERS + 1];
    size_t sizeCard;

    printf("Enter card numbers\n");
    scanf("%" STRINGIFY(MAX_NUMBERS) "s", cardNum);
    sizeCard = strlen(cardNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeCard; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", cardNum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```